# Edit silverlight Sample

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I use this Silverlight [sample](http://silverlight.net/community/samples/silverlight-samples/silverlight-picture-viewer/) (Picture Gallery) in my project. 
I want to change Full-screen message but i can't find this message in source code. help me please. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are referring to the message Silverlight displays when Fullscreen mode is entered.

This is performed by the Silverlight plugin itself which is why you can't find it in the source code.  For security reasons this message cannot be customised.

Comment: Thanks Anthony but if i want to localize this sample to another language must be translated this message. how can i do localize it?

Comment: Have you tried it on a system where the users locale is somewhere other than an English one?  If MS haven't thought of that already I'd be really surprised.